# Vulnerability scanner for the custom jquery files

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

Our solution contains jquery and javascript files.
We want to integrate a scanning tool for these files.

We are already using one tool for static code analysis and it is unable to identify the embedded jquery code.

Please suggest what tool I should go for or what tool you use for such task.

Comment: Welcome to the community. We apparently won't do software recommendations afaik, but we have another site on the StackExchange Network named Software Recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two tools for your vulnerability scans, both from [OWASP](https://owasp.org/) to help enhance your current scans.

1. [OWASP ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) which is web application scanner
2. [OWASP Dependency Checker](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck) which will look at your applications manifests and determine vulnerable libraries